# Trying to hide last row in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to hide the last row, if some conditions in my app is met, but if I select the last row in my UITableView my app crashes with.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds [0 .. 10]'
```

This error makes sense, but I don't know how I can fix it.

In my cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
 NSInteger rowsToDisplay = 0;
    if (self.restaurants.count > 0) {

        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
            rowsToDisplay = indexPath.row;
            if([Restaurant getRestaurantFromRemoteID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRestaurantId]].orderSessionActive.boolValue && indexPath.row >= [Restaurant indexPathForRestaurant:[Restaurant getRestaurantFromRemoteID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRestaurantId]] inArray:self.restaurants].row)

            {
                rowsToDisplay = indexPath.row + 1;
            }
        }

        restaurant = self.restaurants[rowsToDisplay];


    }
```

and the numberOfRowsInSection: method.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchBarDisplayContr.searchResultsTableView) {

        return [self.searchResults count];

    } else {
        if ([Restaurant getRestaurantFromRemoteID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRestaurantId]].orderSessionActive.boolValue) {
            if (section == 0) {
                return [self.restaurants count] - 1;
            }
        }else {

            return [self.restaurants count];

        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works and hides the selected cell if the cell is not the last cell in the tableView. How can I get this also to work when the last cell is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rowsToDisplay = indexPath.row + 1;
```

I think this line causes out of bounds error. I don't know why you're increasing the index by one, but :

```
if([Restaurant getRestaurantFromRemoteID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRestaurantId]].orderSessionActive.boolValue && indexPath.row >= [Restaurant indexPathForRestaurant:[Restaurant getRestaurantFromRemoteID:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kRestaurantId]] inArray:self.restaurants].row)
{
    if(indexPath.row + 1 < [self.restaurants count])
        rowsToDisplay = indexPath.row + 1;
}
```

Will fix the problem.